# How to connect JAVA MIDLET to ORACLE/MySQL database Using Netbeans?

Tags: java, database, netbeans, java-me

I got the code for connecting java midlet to mysql in three parts[**midlet,servlet and standard java**]. but netbeans doesn't allow except midlet in Mobile Project which i created from_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**     **file->new project ->java me->mobile application**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cldc doesn't support JDBC API's. You won't be able to connect the database directly. You can use `HttpConnection` for this. See the following links for your reference,

[DataBase Connection Using J2ME](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/02/database-connection-using-j2me.html)

[How to Connect With MYSQL Database On J2ME](http://www.digit.lk/10_april_j2me)

[Nokia forum discussion](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?188938-How-to-Connect-J2ME-with-MySQL)

Comment: thanks but i have already viewed those links and what i am getting problem at is : netbeans not allowing me to put servlets in mobile project...